# Transform's input file does not exist

Tags: android, gradle

my module can't build because of error below:

What went wrong:
Transform's input file does not exist: C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\Gattexx\app\libs\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar.

what i have tried,
cleaning the project
Invalidating cache

Build grandle (app)

```
       plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
       id 'kotlin-android'
       }

 android {
   compileSdkVersion 30
   buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vale.gattexx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
 }

dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: No i didn't know how to solve the error